# How to extract elevation data from historical imagery in Google Earth?

Tags: dem, google-earth, historical-imagery, google-elevation-api

I am trying to estimate landslide debris volume. The commonly used technique is to create a pre-event DEM and a Post-event DEM, and subtract them. This process involves buying stereopair imagery and it can be expensive when you are working in a large area. I was wondering if there is any way to extract the elevation data from historical image functionality on Google Earth Pro.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You need stereo pairs.  What part of the world are you in? In the USA  individual states often distribute (or have in archive) historical aerial imagery available for free. Google Earth Engine also has a lot of data available.  https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm from India so its pretty hard to get free data.